# Proof inequality for quadrature

Tags: integration, inequality

I have a short question. how can i proof
$\int_{a}^b \vert \alpha x + \beta \vert^2 \, dx \leq (b-a) \left( \vert \alpha a + \beta \vert^2 + \vert \alpha b + \beta \vert^2 \right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)=(\alpha x+\beta)^2$ attains its max at end points of  $[a,b]$ namely $a$ or $b$. So $(\alpha x+\beta)^2\leq \max\big\{(\alpha a+\beta)^2,\: (\alpha b+\beta)^2\big\}\leq (\alpha a+\beta)^2+(\alpha b+\beta)^2$.

Therefore $\int_a^b (\alpha x+\beta)^2\leq(b-a)\Big((\alpha a+\beta)^2+(\alpha b+\beta)^2\Big)$